# Does using multi hurt redis reliable queue performance

Tags: redis, message-queue

I've implemented something similar to redis's reliable que pattern. Where you have two lists. One waiting to be processed listA and another list of currently processed items listB.

I currently have 8 workers whose pattern is the following.

1. 80 rpoplpush listA listB in a multi.exec
2. process the 80 items
3. if item fails lpush listA item
4. when each item is finished lrem 1 item
5. wait for all 80 items to finish
6. repeat

So my question is am I unintentionally blocking access to both lists by starting the process off in a multi?. Checking the rate at which items are getting removed from the listA, it looks like only one of the 8 worker's 80 items are getting placed in the processing que at once.

To improve performance should I convert step one to only accept 1 item at a time and remove step 5 entirely? Will this still be considered safe, when multiple worker are performing this action at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Redis gets blocked only when you send a command and the whole command is being processed. I would say you produce small interruptions.

The best advise here should be *try to perform operations against Redis when it's required and avoid accessing it if you can evaluate something in your application layer*.

I doubt moving 80 items should be an issue here...